# How to call a Web Page an automatically fill up a Form passing a String

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I use asp.net 4 c sharp.

I would like populate a input text form with a string sent by an User.

The destination page is:
http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_demo_ip

*NOTE: im not the developer for the target page.*

Here ho should work:

When a visitor from my site click a link (Ip address)
it will be sent to: http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_demo_ip
and the TextBox automatically populates with the value (Ip address the user has clicked).

The user Will manually click the button "Look Up IP addresses" in maxmind.com to have the result.

Any idea how to do it? Maybe a sample of code?
Thanks guys as usual for your great support! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can, generate a link with this form :

`http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_demo_ip?ip=XX.XX.XX.XX`

then, the page can access this value using `txt1.Text = Page.Request.QueryString["ip"]`

*[Edit] it assumes that you are the developer of the target page... is it ?*

You tells me you are not the developper.

Either maxmind provide an url syntax similar to the one below (check if there is an api section, or you will have to inject with javascript the value. In this case, you have to know :

- for security reason, to avoid a cross site scripting attack, you can't pilot an external site from one page to the other. You can maybe add your application in the trusted zone of the client computer, but it's not possible in an internet application
- nothing guaranties that the html structure of maxmind won't change in the future. you can't rely on this.

An another approach would be to "proxy" the features of maxmin by calling yourself from your server application the target page, with a Http Post request. Then you can parse the results to use it on your application. Again, some limitations are to consider :

- maxmind may **disallow** such calls. They may want the user to use their application
- again, the target page may change its structure and the textbox names
- parsing the result can give headache... and the output structure may change (again)
- you have to handle yourself the UI related to this feature.

A final though : what is your goal ? maybe there are other ways to achieve it.

Comment: NOT im not the developer for the target page. Any Ideas?? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Steve for your explanation